# change from transmission to qbittorrent

Tags: files, lubuntu, qbittorrent

I'd like to change the associated magnet link application from transmission to qbittorrent.
I'm running Lubuntu 12.10.

I've tried this so far and its still opening magnet links with transmission.

> > gconftool-2 -t string -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/magnet/command "/usr/bin/qbittorrent" gconftool-2 -s
> >     /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/magnet/needs_terminal false -t bool
> >     gconftool-2 -t bool -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/magnet/enabled true

best regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to associate magnet links to qBittorrent?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/379921/how-to-associate-magnet-links-to-qbittorrent)

Answer (score 1):

In Xubuntu and Ubuntu I always uninstall Transmission and then install qBittorent.  If you are using Firefox then when it asks you for a program to open the magnet, then go to /usr/bin/qbittorent to assign.  Chrome seems to pick it up automatically for me.