# How to associate magnet links to qBittorrent?

Tags: qbittorrent

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.03 LTS and have installed qBittorrent v2.9.7 via the Ubuntu software center. But where can I find this program in the file system. I need that in order to define magnet in Firefox Edit/Preferences/Applications.

Answer (score 7):

To start qbittorrent, just search for it in Dash, or just type `qbittorrent` in terminal.

[image]

To associate magnet links to qBittorrent in Firefox: Edit --> Preferences --> Applications tab Then type magnet in the search box. Select qbitorrent as your default application; other wise search for it.

[image]

Comment: This shouldn't be the top answer... `other wise search for it` was the information OP was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Warning: All of the other answers here are completely wrong and mislead people into editing browser settings...

Here's the **correct** way of assigning qBittorrent as the default:

- If multiple applications on your system can handle those filetypes, then ".torrent" files and magnet links may currently be associated with something other than qBittorrent. First, let's list all installed handlers for those filetypes.

```
gio mime application/x-bittorrent
gio mime x-scheme-handler/magnet
```

- Next, associate them both with qBittorrent.

```
gio mime application/x-bittorrent org.qbittorrent.qBittorrent.desktop
gio mime x-scheme-handler/magnet org.qbittorrent.qBittorrent.desktop
```

- You can now check the first two commands again to see if they're associated as the default "GIO" (GLib2) handler. And then run this too, to verify that they're also the default "XDG-MIME" handler (which GIO should have taken care of automatically).

```
xdg-mime query default application/x-bittorrent
xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/magnet
```

- Alright, you're finally done and can now enjoy qBittorrent!

*Bonus: If your system lacks `gio` (GLib2), you can instead set the mime-type handlers via `xdg-mime default org.qbittorrent.qBittorrent.desktop <mimetype>` where `<mimetype>` is each of the two types described above. As far as I know, both tools interact with the same internal database at `~/.config/mimeapps.list`, but `gio` is easier to use.*

Answer (score 4):

qBittorrent is in `/usr/bin/qbittorrent` as can be seen here http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/i386/qbittorrent/filelist

Answer (score 1):

To find the full path to any executable in any version of Linux, open a terminal window and enter `whereis executable` (substituting the program you wish to find for the word *executable*). That command will return with the path to the executable file.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/whereis provides more information on the *whereis* command.

Comment: I prefer `type executable` instead.