# Torrent Problems

Tags: bittorrent

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 with GNOME  environment .
I installed qBitTorrent and removed the base package Transmission
can any one please tell me how to make qBitTorrent a default application to torrents.
and 
also how to download magnetic links with qBitTorrent.

Also the tweaks to make torrent download faster.

Thanks in advance

Comment: posible duplicated http://askubuntu.com/questions/379921/how-to-associate-magnet-links-to-qbittorrent

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on the .torrent file and select properties,now in the *open with* tab select qBittorent and then click on the *set as default* button on the bottom.

Now **qBittorent** would be set as a default application for *.torrent* files.