# unable to download torrent in my ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, torrent-client

I have installed BitTorrent , Transmission , K torrent , Vaduz etc.
But I am not able to download any torrent files.I have already tried every thing but i cont do any thing. Could you help me with the answer please ..

I have installed ubuntu 14.04

Comment: i am using 14.04 ubantu operating system.

Comment: Your download is not starting using torrent file. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Also confirm whether you have access/rights to download the file to your desired folder.

Comment: when it fails what errors are given ? you need to provide a lot more info if you want people to help

Comment: I have perched new laptop with ubantu 14.04 operating system.I am using "ACT Fiber Beam" (WIFI)I have installed Qbittorrent to Download movies from torrent web site.But I am not able to download any torrent files,  It is not giving any error message.I am able to add  file in to the Qbittorrent,but it is not downloading(shows added in to the downloads).I have tried different torrent Applications(Bittorrent,Transmission,K torrent..) but the same problem with all applications.

Comment: The least you can do is spelling 'ubantu' correctly and add a question mark (?) to your title to make it a **question** for once. No offence intended!

Answer (score -1):

Right-click on torrent file link and choose `Save file`. A torrent file should be created in your `Downloads` or `home` folder. Click on that file and it should automatically open with a torrent software. Make sure you don't mistake *magnet link* for torrent file. Some torrent sites don't provide torrent files anymore, just magnet links. Magnet links cannot be downloaded as a file, they can only be opened directly by torrenting software.

If a magnet link doesn't open with any torrent software (it is not associated with any such program), just *click-and-drag* the magnet link into a torrent program window. That should open the magnet link.

Tutorial about how to associate magnet links with qbittorent here: [How to associate magnet links to qBittorrent?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/379921/how-to-associate-magnet-links-to-qbittorrent)

Comment: I have perched new laptop with ubantu 14.04 operating system.I am using "ACT Fiber Beam" (WIFI)I have installed Qbittorrent to Download movies from torrent web site.But I am not able to download any torrent files, It is not giving any error message.I am able to add file in to the Qbittorrent,but it is not downloading(shows added in to the downloads).I have tried different torrent Applications(Bittorrent,Transmission,K torrent..) but the same problem with all applications.

Comment: So, let me get this clearly: You CAN download .torrent files and you can ADD them to qbittorrent, but you can't see 'the end result', can't see the files qbittorrent is supposed to download (as described by the .torrent file). It might be a problem of network ports. Usually, every internet app uses an specific internet port (e.g. 78, 84, 7865, 10965, etc). Go to qbittorrent Settings menu and check the option to use random port. And check your firewall (/add a rule if needed) to allow torrent connections.

Comment: @ipse lute  Question is not about how to download using torrent file. He is able to open the torrent file in the said applications but the download is not starting and remains in that state forever.

Comment: @DhavalSimaria:`... not able to download any torrent files.` Do you, or he, know what a .torrent file is? Maybe should edit question for clarity: `...not able to download any movies using torrenting software.`

Comment: @ipselute I very well know and probably he also knows what .torrent file is. It's you who is not able to make out what is asked in the question. He is probably newbie and hence he wrote such ambiguous sentence `not able to download any torrent files`. But then he has repeatedly clarified in the comments which you must read.